# int i = 1; - Is there any way to make Eclipse's auto-complete/intellisense any less annoying?

Tags: eclipse

I am new to Eclipse and am developing for Android.  I'm coming from a .NET background and have been spoiled by Microsoft's excellent Intellisense system.  I'm finding that Eclipse's version of that to be more of a nuisance than it is helpful.  I don't want to shut it off, because I still use it a lot.. but I find it getting in the way more often than not.

Take this, for example:

```
int i = 1;
```

Simple enough, right?  Well if you type that into Eclipse, you get:

```
integer i context=Context 1;
```

Here's what happens as you type each part of `int i = 1;`:

- `int<spacebar>` turns into `integer`
- `i<spacebar>`
- `=` turns into `context=`
- `<spacebar>` turns `context=` into `context=Context`
- `1;`

The spacebar is constantly auto-correcting valid language.  `int` is a perfectly valid start to a new line of code yet Eclipse, for whatever reason, decides it would rather use something else.

Is there any way to improve this?  I am getting really tired of fighting Eclipse even with the most basic of code.

Comment: I get "int i = 1;" ...

Comment: what language are you using? And perhaps more importantly, what language does eclipse think you are using?

Comment: You probably need to clean-install Eclipse. This would not happen in a default installation of Eclipse Java. *In other words, this is just you.* :)

Answer (score 0):

You've made "space" automatically activate content assist when "space" also inserts the selected proposal (which is behavior you can not change) and the default is to automatically insert the proposal if only one is proposed.  STOP IT. Stop trying to use it like you use Visual Studio.